# Настроить апач так, чтобы "сайт смотрел в корень"

Tags: apache, html, php

Всем привет. Работаю на локальной машине, windows 7, использую xampp. По дефолту работает так, что есть папка htdocs, в ней сайты:

```
c:\htdocs\my-site1\index.html
c:\htdocs\my-site2\index.html
c:\htdocs\my-site3\index.html
```

Соответствено, в браузере это работает как

```
http://localhost/my-site1
http://localhost/my-site2
http://localhost/my-site3
```

Для верстки этого всегда было достаточно. Но сейчас есть необходимость работы в паре с программистами и разрабатываемом на yii framework проекте. Там что-то по-другому с путями, как говорят прогеры, они "от корня". Нужно перенастроить апач таким образом, чтобы сайты открывались как-нибудь так:

```
http://my-site1.localhost/
http://my-site2.localhost/
http://my-site3.localhost/
```

ну или хотя бы так, чтобы текущий сайт был доступен просто как

```
localhost/
```

потому что все пути на сайте выглядят как

```
localhost/about
localhost/img/sprite.png
```

и т.д.

Для конфигурирования мне доступны файлики httpd.conf

С другой стороны, может быть, можно как-нибудь сконфигурировать сам проект на Yii, прописав в конфиге сайта какую-нибудь переменную для корня?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого нужно настроить виртуальные хосты в Apache. Как это сделать, для xampp, достаточно подробно описано [тут](http://design-for.net/page/nastrojka-virtualnyh-hostov). Строго двигайтесь по мануалу и у вас все получится.

Comment: Спасибо, пробую.

Comment: Все получилось. Спасибо. Возможно ли обобщить эту схему для сайта с произвольным именем?

Что-то типа 

http://*.local/

c:\htdocs\*\index.html

чтобы для каждого сайта не прописывать каждый раз одно и тоже?

Comment: Я не нашел такую возможность. возможно для этого существует какая либо утилита. Точно сказать не могу.

Answer (score 1):

Поставьте OpenServer и создавайте сколько угодно виртуальных доменов (читай "сайтов от корня") без всяких проблем с конфигами. Он сам все настроит и запустит "как надо".

Comment: Спасибо. Сначала попробую вариант с настройкой виртуальных хостов. Это будет план "б", знач :)